# Make <div> link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble making  link.

I have a slide in a Magento store. Theme is responsive and slider is javascript.

This is the code i have:

```
<div id="camera_wrap" class="camera_wrap camera_orange_skin">
<div data-thumb="{{skin url='images/camera/slides/thumbs/slide1-thumb.png'}}" data-src {{skin url='images/camera/slides/b1.jpg'}}"></div>
</div>
```

Slider is showing picture and assosiated thumbnail. I want to make slider clickable but i cant get it working. Any ideas?
If i place

```
onclick="location.href='newurl.html';"
```

inside div, image is not showing :(
Any suggestions?

Comment: You are missing =" after data-src. It prob. should be: data-src="{{skin url='images/camera/slides/b1.jpg'}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use inline onclicks... Assign your div a class and a custom data attribute. Example:

```
<div class="onclick-link" data-href="mylink.html">Some content here...</div>
```

And then:

```
$('.onclick-link').unbind('click').click(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-href');
});
```

This can be used for all div's you want to turn into a link, bu assigning the class and the data-href attribute.

Comment: @ EibergDK Still cant get it working. I loaded script and added class + href i page. Nothing happens :( This is template i am working on [link](http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/41217.html). You can see the slider there. Dont know if that is any help for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="newurl.html">My link</a>
```

The easiest (and most semantic) way to make a link, is to use the `<a>` element.
If you REALLY want to go the javascript way, you can bind a handler using jQuery

```
$('#camera_wrap').on('click', function(){
 // your code
});
```